# Среда разработки не видит таблицу в базе данных

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite3

Я пишу телеграмм-бота на aiogram 2.24, который при команде /start заносит username, а также имя и фамилию в базу данных. Среда разработки выдаёт ошибку **sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user**, хотя я вроде создал таблицу, используя визуальный интерфейс "DB Browser for SQLite".
Мой код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import asyncio
import sqlite3

TOKEN_API = "TOKEN"

bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)



@dp.message_handler()
async def mess(message: types.Message):
    if message.text=='/start':
        conn = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Проверяем, есть ли уже такая учетная запись по username
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='{message.from_user.username}'")
        existing_account = cursor.fetchone()

        # Если учетная запись не существует, добавляем новую запись в базу данных
        if not existing_account:
            name=message.from_user.first_name+" "+message.from_user.last_name
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user (username, name) VALUES ('{message.from_user.username}', '{name}')")
            conn.commit()
            print("Учетная запись успешно добавлена")
        else:
            print("Учетная запись уже существует")

        conn.close()
    else:
        await message.answer(text="Неизвестная команда. Пишите /start чтобы начать диалог")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Как вы понимаете, вместо TOKEN в кавычках стоит токен моего бота.

Comment: Может это другой файл с базой, может у вас их несколько в разных каталогах? )

Comment: трейсбек ошибки можно?

Comment: @BArbosspirat 

 
 Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-12' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\projects\scambot27-02-2024\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=OperationalError('no such table: user')>
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @CrazyElf да не, там только одна база в той же папке что и питон файл

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему тут люди пытаются помочь человеку, у которого название проекта `scambot`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Так это знание появилось уже после того, как мы начали помогать пытаться

Comment: @ClarkDevlin я изначально хотел сделать пранк-бота который напишет моему другу и предложит ему купить кое-какой незаконный медиа-контент, а когда он нажмёт "посмотреть бесплатные пробные примеры" ему выложится его фотка, все данные о нём и контакт его родителей, но потом я узнал что боты не могут инициализировать диалог и теперь просто пытаюсь сделать какой-то пет-проект работающий с базой данных

Comment: попробуйте создать таблицу запросом, вдруг поможет